# How to render an unresponsive button via HTML (for illustration purposes)

Tags: html, css, button, mouseover, mousedown

How do I render a normal (enabled-looking) button, via HTML/CSS, which doesn't change its appearance upon mouse over or mouse down (for illustration purposes e.g. Press [x] to cancel)?

(i.e. I don't want it to become "highlighted" or "pushed" when you hover the mouse over it or "press" it.)

I know I can use a picture of the button, but under different or future versions of browsers the subsequent real buttons may look different and not match the picture, which is why I'm looking to render it via HTML/CSS.

Comment: If I understand correctly, give `border:none; margin:0;` (or give as your wish)

Comment: As I said in my example simply putting a button on the page with no functionality will show it's appearance in all states without actually doing anything. http://jsfiddle.net/TfSer/

Comment: I don't want it to respond in any way to mouse over (like turn highlighted) or mouse down (like be pushed).

Comment: no it basically makes the button plain text in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/TfSer/2/

Comment: yes it does make the button plain text but I assume the OP can design it to look like button or more better.  http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/TfSer/3/

Comment: Yeah but he wants it to appear as it will in all the different browsers, id Chrome renders buttons differently than Firefox. Honestly use images and then detect the browser to swap the images. I really don't understand the need for this but to each their own I suppose.

Comment: Good idea Rick. Problem might be future versions of browsers might take on different styles.

Answer (score 0):

The [disabled attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) is supported in all major browsers, so you could use that.

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

or, alternatively:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" disabled />
```

To make it look like it's enabled, you could then edit its CSS properties for it's disabled state:

```
input[type="button"]:disabled, button[type="button"]:disabled {
  background:#DDD;
  color:#000;
}
```

But, as OP pointed out, this can make it appear completely different to what other buttons look like on certain browsers/systems. You could omit the background property in the CSS rule and they would render as any other disabled buttons, but with font color like enabled buttons. Alternatively, omit the disabled HTML attribute and position these buttons out of context they would normally belong to (being a part of a form).

**EDIT: See [Antony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550110/how-to-render-an-unresponsive-button-via-html-for-illustration-purposes/14550161#14550161) for better explanation what styles need to be applied to make it appear like you expect them to** ;)

Comment: it was my first thought too, but.. it's disabled now

Comment: Disabled means the button doesn't change state.

Comment: _To make it look like it's enabled, you could then edit its CSS properties for it's disabled state:_ What if In my system/browser default buttons comes with green background and yellow text? Different OS/browser/system theme = Different default button style

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski -  well frankly, I have no idea LOL. Disabling a SUBMIT button with JavaScript isn't a good idea as it would still try to SUBMIT on browsers with JS disabled. Perhaps a better idea is to simply use a normal button that's out of context (not part of any form) and have it do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can force a disabled button to look just like a normal one using CSS.

**DEMO**

- Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/9aXW9/2/
- Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/gZtT7/

<sup>IE buried its CSS in the registry. But as a general rule, apply `color: #000;` and other modifications would make it look like a normal button.</sup>

**HTML**

```html
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="I cannot be pressed." />
```

**CSS**

```css
/* Safari */
input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: ButtonText;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px;
    border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: pre;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    -moz-appearance: button;
    padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
    border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    color: ButtonText; 
    font: -moz-button;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    cursor: default;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-binding: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Read the question, he wants to illustrate functionality of the button but have it not actually do anything.

Comment: @RickCalder the question reads `which doesn't change its appearance upon mouse over or mouse down`

Comment: I considered this route too, until I realized what was going to happen. Your button looks like a Safari button in my Chrome. This works but he'd have to detect the browser type and change the default css accordingly.

Comment: @RickCalder This looks like a Windows button on my Mac's Firefox. What I am trying to do is to illustrate the point only, i.e., it is possible with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Yep I wasn't saying it wasn't a viable response but it ends up being quite complicated that's all. I'm still trying to figure out why you'd want this to begin with. I fail to see why having the button change state for illustration purposes is a bad thing.

Comment: Rick - because it's not supposed to be a real button?

Comment: @Navigateur You will know it by the time you press it - nothing happens.

Comment: Anthony, do I need more CSS to recognize "ButtonFace" in your example?

Comment: @Navigateur I guess "ButtonFace" is applicable to Safari (or webkit) only (since I copied from there). Other browsers would simply ignore it. You may wish to detect different browsers and pull up their respective default.css and overwrite the `:disabled` style with that of ordinary buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider placing an empty `<div>` with a specified width and height overlapping the button, which will occlude the click on the button?

Depending the positioning modes of your outer elements, you can use the `<div>` to cover some outer element, or just the `<input type="button" ...>` itself (in which case JavaScript and DOM can be helpful to determine the actual size of the button and thus the coverage area).

Answer (score 0):

@Navigeteur

just take a screenshot of a normal button and save it as bmp or png image
 and render the image instead of button :)